# Using Tcl/Tk can canvas tags be configured before using them on an item?

Tags: canvas, tags, tcl, tk-toolkit

Using Tcl/Tk can canvas tags be configured before using them on an item?

For example i have the following snippet:

```
.canvas create rectangle [list 10 10 200 100] -tags t1
```

Here the rectangle is being created with the tag `t1` and i can configure this tag like this:

```
.canvas itemconfigure t1 -fill red
```

Which fills the rectangle with red because it is assigned this tag.

Is there a way i can specify the tag first, then dynamically assign these tags to other items at runtime or do tags need to exist attached to an item before they can be configured?

I have a script which tries to do the tag configuration first, then applies the tag to an item and nothing changes. I know the tag is assigned to the item, it's just that the tag doesn't seem to have been previously configured. So this begs the question how to create a tag without assigning it to an item?

Comment: Hmm, to me it seems like an event loop would suit here; one which will detect the creation of an item in the canvas and when that occurs, call the `itemconfigure`. It could use `.canvas find all` to get the list of current items and if it grew, configure the tags of the last item created. Not sure if that will be okay for you though.

Comment: Tags themselves don't really have an identity; they're just a labelling of canvas items. (They _appear_ to work for bindings, but that's because the labelling is evaluated at the time that the event arrives. IIRC anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, here's a `proc` that 'listens' to additions of items within a canvas called `.c`.

```
package require Tk

canvas .c
pack .c
set citem [list]  ;# list kept by the proc

proc item_config {} {
  global citem
  set litem [.c find all]  ;# Get list of current items in .c
  if {[llength $litem] > [llength $citem]} {
    set tags [.c gettags [lindex $litem end]]       ;# get latest addition
    set code {.c itemconfigure [lindex $litem end]} ;# code to be executed
    set changes 1                                   ;# 0 means no changes
    foreach tag $tags {
      switch $tag {
        t1 {append code " -fill red"}             ;# if tag is t1, fill red
        t2 {append code " -outline black"}        ;# if tag is t2, outline black
        default {set changes 0}                   ;# if no tags, no change
      }
    }
    if {$changes} {eval $code}                    ;# eval the built code
    set citem $litem                              ;# update list of items
  }
  after 100 "item_config"                         ;# recurse
}
item_config
```

Note: The above proc does not take into consideration any deletion of items. To cater for that, you could compare `$citem` and `$litem` to see if any element of one list is not in another and process only the one that is not in `$citem`.

If you do `.c create rectangle 0 0 100 100 -tags "t1 t2"` that will create a rectangle with coords `{0 0 100 100}` that has a fill of red and black outline.